# How to use class instead of ID for Material Design Lite tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

I need to take `class` instead of `id` for `data-mdl-for` to use multiple tooltips in JavaScript. My Tooltip buttons will be generated by JSON.

```
<button id="tooltip" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
    <i class="material-icons lighticon">content_copy</i>
        <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--left" data-mdl-for="tooltip">
          Copy
        </div>
</button>
```

This works fine but I need to use multiple above button elements. Is there a possible way to convert this `id` of button and `data-mdl-for` to Javascript and use something like `querySelector` or `getElementsByClassName` for a working Tooltip?

```
var a = document.querySelector('.mdl-button');
a.data-mdl-for = "tooltip"
```

I know this is a wrong script but this can explain what I really need. I need a working tooltip with JavaSript instead of using `data-mdl-for` or specify the `data-mdl-for` in javascript and use button class.

Comment: [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) for setting attributes with a `-` in them.

Comment: @Emil S could you show an example?

Answer (score 2):

```js
//Get list
var mdlButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".mdl-button");
//Iterate over list
for (var i = 0; i < mdlButtons.length; i++) {
  //find child tooptip
  var child = mdlButtons[i].querySelector(".mdl-tooltip");
  if (child === null) {
    continue;
  }
  //Modify list
  child.setAttribute("data-mdl-for", mdlButtons[i].getAttribute("id"));
  console.log(child);
}
//Show a list of ".mdl-button" where we can see it has been modified
console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll(".mdl-button")
);
```

```html
<button id="tooltip-1" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons lighticon">content_copy</i>
  <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--left">
    Copy
  </div>
</button>
<button id="tooltip-2" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons lighticon">content_copy</i>
  <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--left">
    Copy
  </div>
</button>
<button id="tooltip-3" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons lighticon">content_copy</i>
  <div class="mdl-tooltip mdl-tooltip--left">
    Copy
  </div>
</button>
```

Comment: tried this in codepen. Only the 1st button works and others doesnt. http://codepen.io/shmshd12/pen/JRdaqw

Comment: @shmshd17 the trick is to keep the ID of the top button unique or the won't know what to bind to. I have made an updated [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgpGqo).

Comment: is there any other way to use `class` instead of `id`?

Comment: Then it wouldn't know which element to bind with?

Comment: if using with class then i can use `('.mdl-button.mdl-js-button')`  class this way right? It will then bind all those HTML tags with that class. Is that way possible?